# проблемы с кодировкой при прочтении txt файла андройд

Tags: java, android, файлы, кодировка, текст

помогите пожалуйста бьюсь с этим дня 2 уже. во внешней памяти есть текстовый файл по нажатию на кнопку в`TextView` выводится текст файла. и английский читает а русский нет. были дикие танцы с бубном перепробованы все русские кодировки. кодировка проекта `utf-8`. подумала может ошиблась и поставила текущую кодировку в параметре чтоб точно правильно было. все равно `кракзябры` выдает.`try {
                    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(myFile);

```
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                try {
                    SortedMap<String, Charset> charsets = Charset.availableCharsets();//список доступных кодировок

                    Charset currentCharset = Charset.defaultCharset();//узнать текущую кодировку

                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){


                          String secondString = new String(line.getBytes(currentCharset), "windows-1251");
                    //    String secondString2 = new String(secondString.getBytes("UTF-8"), "windows-1251");

                          stringBuilder.append(secondString);
                        System.out.println(secondString);
                        cv.setText(stringBuilder);//это TextView

                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }`
```

Comment: Кодировку нужно указывать в конструкторе `InputStreamReader`, ваш способ не даст адекватного результата, потому что `readLine()` уже неправильно раскодировал байты в символы и далеко не всегда `getBytes` вернёт оригинальные. Дефолтная кодировка при чтении файла играет роль только если вы не указали свою в конструкторе. Главную роль играет кодировка самого файла - её лучше знать заранее, либо определять по сигнатурам (что возможно в редких случаях, поэтому текстовые редакторы далеко не все кодировки могут определять автоматически)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы уверены в кодировке файла, то можно попробовать этот метод:

```
private String readString(String path){
    try {
        DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
        String toReturn = stream.readUTF();
        stream.close();
        Log.i("Считанная строка", toReturn);
        return toReturn;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

Если вы не уверены в кодировке файла, то не плохо было бы посмотреть его в HEX редакторе и попереключать кодировки, или попробовать [онлайн декодеры](https://www.artlebedev.ru/decoder/advanced/)

Я как то писал распознавание ID3v2 тегов и там жуткая белеберда с русскими буквами, через стандартные ни чего не получилось, пришлось распознавать их побайтово. Возможно что то поможет

```
 /**
 * Байты в строки.
 * @param bytes Байты Если первый байт 01 - то Unicode, если 00 - ISO_8859_1.
 * @return Строки
 */
public static String bytesToString(byte[] bytes){

    if (bytes.length < 3) return "";

    boolean isUnicode = bytes[0] == 0x01; // else 0x00 =  ISO_8859_1

    if (isUnicode) {

        byte[] clearByte = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes,1,bytes.length);
        return unicodeToString(clearByte);

    }

    return clear8859(Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes,1, bytes.length));

}

/**
 * Вспомогательный к переводу байт в строки
 * @param clearByte Байты юникоде начиная с FF FE или FE FF
 * @return Текстовая строка
 */
private static String unicodeToString(byte[] clearByte) {

    boolean isUnicodeNormal = (clearByte[0] & 0b11111111) == 0b11111111 && (clearByte[1] & 0x11111110) == 0x11111110;
    boolean isUnicodeRevers = (clearByte[1] & 0x11111110) == 0x11111110 && (clearByte[0] & 0b11111111) == 0b11111111;

    if (isUnicodeNormal) {

        StringBuilder inString = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 2, s = 0; i < clearByte.length; i++) {

            if (i % 2 == 0) {

                int ch = ((clearByte[i + 1] << 8) | (clearByte[i]));

                if( ch==0 && clearByte.length-(i+2)>0 ){

                    String newRow =
                            unicodeToString
                                    (Arrays.copyOfRange
                                            (clearByte, i+2, clearByte.length));

                    inString.append("\n"+newRow);

                    return inString.toString();

                }else { inString.append((char)ch); }

            }
        }

        return inString.toString();

    }
    else if (isUnicodeRevers) {

        int[] retByte = new int[(clearByte.length - 1) / 2];

        for (int i = 2, s = 0; i < clearByte.length; i++) {

            if (i % 2 == 0) {

                retByte[s] = ((clearByte[i] << 8) | (clearByte[i + 1]));
                if(retByte[s]==0){
                    unicodeToString(Arrays.copyOfRange(clearByte,s,clearByte.length));
                    continue;
                }
                s++;

            }
        }
        return new String(retByte, 0, retByte.length);

    }

    return "";
}

private static String clear8859(byte[] bytes){

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(byte b : bytes){
        if((b)!=0x00){
            builder.append((char)b);
        }
        else {
            builder.append(' ');
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: спасибо огромное. не догадалась что файл в непонятно какой кодировке сохраняется